# Is there a way to see the SQL executed by Rapid SQL for stored procs?

Tags: rapidsql

Using the Embarcadero Rapid SQL client tool, you may list Procedures from a database, right-click one a choose "Execute" which opens up a dialog where you can enter the input parameter values, then click the Execute button to run the procedure and see the results grid.

But I dont see anywhere that shows me what SQL the tool ended up running- is there a way to enable this output so that I may view it, copy it, share it with colleagues or run the SQL directly if I need to?

Comment: Are yo using rapid to connect with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on SQL Server you may run SQL Server Profiler (under Tools/ SQL Server Profiler) and trace the querys that you are run it in the database engine. In the column of application name you will see "Rapid" or something like that. This is very useful to track all T-SQL (included store procedures by the way) statements executed in the engine.